# Is the local cargo registry portable?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

As in I copy the `/path/to/home/.cargo/registry` directory (or the `/path/to/home/.cargo/registry/src` directory specifically), from my system and replace the one in a different system with this copy and the same set of crates are available now in that system (by "available" I mean that I can include those crates in a project as dependencies and build it with `cargo build --offline` or vendor them into my project with `cargo vendor --offline`, after adding them to `Cargo.toml`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never tried it but in theory, copying the contents of `~/.cargo/registry` from one system to another should work. `~/.cargo/registry` is a source cache rather than a build cache containing compiled artefacts which may not be transferable depending on the two systems you have. It contains the source code of your dependencies, both packed (`~/.cargo/registry/cache`) and unpacked (`~/.cargo/registry/src`). If you copy something, **copy the packed versions** (the `.crate` files located in `~/.cargo/registry/cache`), as Cargo uses them to lookup dependencies and unpacks them for you, once they are required by one of your projects. Read more about the `~/.cargo` directory (called "Cargo Home") in the [Cargo Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/cargo-home.html).

Instead of working with the source cache directly though, you should prefer `cargo vendor`, as it is the command specifically designed for such use-cases.